# My hands are moving

Tags: riddle

The more complications I have, the more others want me,

Yet my face is easily read.

I only had to tell you one thing and you’d be fine with me,

These days you look elsewhere for the same.

Thanks to all the jewels I’ve been given,

I’m a little more punctilious when I’m at work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> It's a mechanical watch.

---

My hands are moving

> Watch hands.

The more complications I have, the more others want me,

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complication_%28horology%29

Yet my face is easily read.

> Even on a watch with many complications, the time is generally largest and easiest to read.

I only had to tell you one thing and you’d be fine with me,

> The time

These days you look elsewhere for the same.

> Many other things tell time these days (but could refer to a cell phone?)

Thanks to all the jewels I’ve been given,

I’m a little more punctilious when I’m at work.

> Jewel bearings ("jewels") make watches more accurate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_bearing

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! I'd thought jewels and complications would be a giveaway.

Comment: I clicked on the wikipedia link and learned today that clicking on a spoiler toggles it between always show and show on hover.

Answer (score 7):

How about a:

> Quartz Crystal Watch

The more complications I have, the more others want me,

> More features/luxuries = more demand

Yet my face is easily read.

> It is still just a basic watch

I only had to tell you one thing and you’d be fine with me,

> Time

These days you look elsewhere for the same.

> Cell phone

Thanks to all the jewels I’ve been given,
I’m a little more punctilious when I’m at work.

> Quartz Crystals are [VERY good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_clock) at precision time keeping.

Comment: I was just about to write this up as an answer!! +1, in any event, for writing up much better than I probably would have. Welcome to Puzzling :)

Answer (score 6):

My guess is a

> watch, potentially one of the new iWatches.

The more complicated I am, the more others want me,
Yet my face is easily read.

> Watches are really complicated, and having one can be a source of bragging, also, watches are (should be) easy to read

I only had to tell you one thing and you’d be fine with me,

> Just tells time

These days you look elsewhere for the same.

> I know I whip out my phone to check the time.

Thanks to all the jewelry I’ve been given,
I’m a little more punctilious when I’m at work.

> Not fully sure, watches have been bling'd out? Maybe the cool new watches are on top of all your activities?

Comment: It's a watch, but it's certainly not an iWatch. The jewelry has a purpose.

Comment: @itriedacrab Are you looking for a specific brand of watch?

Comment: @AggieKidd Not a specific brand.

Comment: @itriedacrab Then a specific type? Basically, are you content with "watch" or are you looking for a little more?

Comment: @AggieKidd Just a little bit more.

Comment: Honestly, for that last line, I've got nothing.

Comment: This was meant to be an easy riddle, I'll make some edits to make it clear.

Comment: @JonTheMon if I could get any feedback I'd appreciate it. I'm starting to second-guess whether my riddle was any good at all, and if it was still too broad to warrant a more specific answer.

Comment: Up until the end, it's fine. It's just the specific knowledge about jewels that's a hiccup. Most people probably think of them as just decorations, but those in the know get that they help with timekeeping.

Comment: I'd agree with JonTheMon's statement about specifics, but it's hard to avoid that on a site such as this. Most of the puzzles require some specific knowledge that may or may not be widely known.

Answer (score 6):

Surely it's an

> analogue watch

The more complications I have, the more others want me,

> [Complications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complication_%28horology%29) make watches more expensive/desirable

Yet my face is easily read.

> A watch's face is easily read to tell the time

I only had to tell you one thing and you’d be fine with me,

> A watch that tells the time is a fine watch

These days you look elsewhere for the same.

> People often tell the time using their phones nowadays

Thanks to all the jewels I’ve been given,
I’m a little more punctilious when I’m at work

> I'm guessing this is about [Jewel bearings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_bearing) making a watch run more accurately.

Comment: This also fits into what I was looking for, but I think Sidnicious answered a little earlier than you did, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @itriedacrab: You're right - I was beaten to it by just a few seconds!

Answer (score 4):

Try 2:

I think it is a:

> Digital Watch

he more complicated I am, the more others want me,

> Some digital watches can tell time, set alarms, check the date, change TV channels, be stopwatches, etc.

Yet my face is easily read.

> Though an analog clock or watch is not difficult, a digital watch just throws it all out there easy as can be.

I only had to tell you one thing and you’d be fine with me,

> You generally only check the time, but you can do a lot of other things.

These days you look elsewhere for the same.

> Today we look at phones, wall clocks, other people, computer clocks, etc.

Thanks to all the jewelry I’ve been given,

> Watches are now as much jewelry as anything else. So shiny!

I’m a little more punctilious when I’m at work

> Your watch can now be used for work items, but also lets you know the exact second meetings should start or end, as well as the workday.

Comment: Nice guess, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

My initial guesses matched these other answers, but from the comments I've gone in a slightly different direction.

I guess:

> Fitness Tracker - I'm imagining the FitBit Charge, but most meet the criteria

The more complications I have, the more others want me,

> The more features they have, the more people want to buy them

Yet my face is easily read.

> Most have a simple display

I only had to tell you one thing and you’d be fine with me,

> The specific model I mentioned tells the time, but others have a simple display telling you want mode they're in (Jawbone) or how many steps you've taken (FitBit Flex)

These days you look elsewhere for the same.

> You can check the time on your phone, and get the fitness information from related smart phone apps.

Thanks to all the jewels I’ve been given,

> All the additional sensors

I’m a little more punctilious when I’m at work.

> The fitness readings get more and more accurate